# Casting generic array in swift cause fatal error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

I have a class which acts as a BLL, wrapping a service protocol. The service protocol provides a list of `SerializableObjectProtocol` objects. For instance, I have `User`, which implements `SerializedObjectProtocol`.

The following function casts a `SerializedObjectProtol` array into a `User`

```
public func Get() -> [T]
{
    let result = self._service.Get()

    return result as! [T]
}
```

As a result, I am getting the following error:

```
 array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C
```

I am aware that the code is error prone, because if the object is not T, down casting cannot happen. As a result, here is what I can verify:

- T in constrained to implement SerializedObjectProtol i.e.

  ```
     class DataLayer<T:SerializableObjectProtocol>
  ```
- T is type User. The `result` is an array of user. i.e. `[User]`
- I can get around this issue, but I have to manually cast each item. As a result, this works perfectly fine:

  ```
  var returnArray = [T]()

  for item in result
  {
      returnArray.append(item as! T)
  }

  return returnArray;
  ```

I have just picked up Swift for a project so I have limited experience with it. As a result, I have gone out to see if what I am trying is possible (casting array [S] to [T]). It seems that it is possible if the array is `[Any]`.

Is this a valid operation in Swift? Or is casting this way not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is not possible to cast directly between an array of `Any` to the type it contains, because `Any` has a completely different representation in memory: `sizeof(Any)` isn't equal to `sizeof(User)`! An array of 10 `Any`s might have a length of 320 bytes, but 10 `User`s only need 80 bytes, the same applies to any protocol. Conclusion: You need to cast every single item.

Maybe do it like this:

```
return results.map{ $0 as! User }
```

or if you're not sure whether every item is a `User`, you can only return the `User`s like this:

```
return results.flatMap{ $0 as? User }
```

If you're still having problems, please post some minimal code that still produces the error, it's really hard to understand what your code looks like without the actual code

Comment: This is good to know. Thank you very much! I've seen articles that do [Any] -> [T], but the internet is not always the best place to learn proper conventions.

Comment: Note: Mixing and matching casting like that is generally not a good idea. In this case, there is absolute certainty that the object is User. The service is setup to return `SerializableObjectProtocol` for services that need serialization (such as WebService which can extract a dictionary of fields/values from and to an object). At this point, if an object is not User, a bug has happened somewhere in the logic chain. Casting selectively like that treats the collection as solid classes and defeats the loose coupling which is encouraged by protocols.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov What purpose has the protocol when it can only ever be a User? Generally I think if you need casts in your (pure) Swift code, you're doing something wrong, I haven't used them at all when programming with pure Swift (no ObjC, no JSON, etc.)

Comment: In this specific context, yes. But being a `SerializableObjectProtocol` allows me to implement any kind of a service without caring what the underlying type actually is. In fact the service itself is defined by `ServiceProtocol`. A service can represent any storage medium and will use the `SerializableObjectProtocol`  protocol to convert to and from the storage type (like a REST web service, or say Sqlite). It's a way to maintain loose coupling with the service, so I can easily swap out the service type, but the functionality of the rest of my application is unaffected.